# An easy question on geometry.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, contest-math

The question says that I have to derive a formula to find the maximum number of enclosed regions formed by $n$ lines. This is how I proceeded:

Let $f(n)$ be the maximum number of enclosed regions formed by $n$ lines. Thus, $f(3) =
1$, $f(4) = 3$ and $f(5)=6$. Therefore, a recursive function is formed which is $f(i) = f(i-1) + (i-2)$. So, for the $i^{th}$ line that is added, $(i-2)$ more enclosed regions are formed. On solving the recursion, I get the formula $\frac{(i-1)(i-2)}{2}$, which defines the maximum number of enclosed regions formed by $i$ lines.

The only problem that I face is that I should I prove that for every $i^{th}$ line that I add, the maximum number of enclosed regions increases by $(i-2)$. That is, for $3$, maximum regions is $1$. When I add the $4^{th}$ line to this, the maximum regions increase by $(4-2)=2$, and thus become $3$. When the $5^{th}$ line is added, the maximum number of enclosed regions increases by $(5-2)=3$, and becomes $6$. How to prove this?

Comment: You enclose a region when you cross a line (other than the first line you cross). Your $n$th line crosses $n-1$ other lines.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So the $n-1$ lines it cuts will produce $n-2$ new regions. and this is simple observation. right?

Comment: I think it is a simple observation. Are you unsure about it?

Comment: Yeah, I am a little unsure about it.

Comment: Draw your $n$th line. There are $n-1$ points on it where it crosses other lines --- call those points, in order, $p_1,\dots,p_{n-1}$. Look at two consecutive points, $p_i$ and $p_{i+1}$. Those are where lines $i$ and $i+1$ cross the $n$th line. Lines $i$ and $i+1$ meet on one side of the $n$th line. The $n$th line has created a new enclosed region on that side of the $n$th line, bordered (in part) by lines $i$, $i+1$, and $n$. Draw a picture!

Comment: What the heck? This is SUMaC Problem 4 (c) in this year's set.

Comment: @Anonymous: Please flag it for the moderators when you see these things as we've had several recent incidents of this. Regards